# Object Spy for Chrome Extensions

Tags: automated-testing, chrome, uiautomation

I need to automate Chrome Extension. But I am trying to avoid tools that use Image recognition of coordinate system. Is there any way to automate or at-least Identify individual Objects on the Extension GUI Not based on Image or coordinate but on the basis of a unique identifier.?

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the Element you want to Inspect and Select option Inspect Element from the context menu.
All the elements on the web page will be displayed and you can inspect the element you want.
If you want to search for any specific xpath,Css selector or want to create one, click on the inspector window and pres Ctrl+F from keyboard.
Now you can type and create xpath and css selector for the web-elements.

Comment: I am trying to automate a Chrome extension in a chrome legacy window. It doesn't have an "Inspect element" Option. so. I am looking for a tool that does Identify.